# Why does the Lichtenberg figure form in one direction?

Tags: high-voltage, electrolysis

In videos such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3E12nnpWc5c) one, we see that the Lichtenberg figure grows from one side to the other, in this case from the left to the right. Why does the figure not grow from both sides and meet somewhere in the middle?

Comment: https://youtu.be/2t8_Euo1tKU

Comment: There's also a nice discussion [here](https://museumtrade.org/embellishing-with-lichtenberg-wood-burning-for-natural-plant-like-formations/).

Comment: DC ... think about the shape of lightning

Comment: @jsotola

Interesting. So they can meet in the middle. Thanks!